# Update database row, else create a new row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to use `REPLACE INTO` to update a row if it exists, and else it has to make a new row.

I am using NOVA framework. Here is what i got:

```
public function updateTicketRows($id,$ticketId, $row, $stock, $price)
{
    $pdo = DB::getPdo();
    return DB::raw('REPLACE INTO ticket_rows (id,ticket_id,row,stock,price)
                    VALUES('.$pdo->quote($id).','.$pdo->quote($ticketId).','.$pdo->quote($row).','.$pdo->quote($stock).','.$pdo->quote($price).')');
}
```

It's called by:

```
foreach ($_POST['ticket'] as $ticket) {
                            $this->itemsModel->updateTicketRows($ticket['ticket_row_id'], $id,$ticket["ticket_row"],
                                $ticket["ticket_stock"],$ticket["ticket_price"]);
                        }
```

However it just doesnt work. No new items are created and no items will be updated.

Any one knows how i can do this?

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: I think your `id` will be auto incremented so it always be new. What you can do is check for id, if found run update query else insert.

Comment: You can use MySQL select exists, if the result is false insert new row otherwise update

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** to handle this situation:

```
return DB::raw('INSERT INTO ticket_rows (id,ticket_id,row,stock,price) '.
                'VALUES('.$pdo->quote($id).','.$pdo->quote($ticketId).','.$pdo->quote($row).','.$pdo->quote($stock).','.$pdo->quote($price).') '.
                'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ticket_id='.$pdo->quote($ticketId).', row='.$pdo->quote($row).', stock='.$pdo->quote($stock).', price='.$pdo->quote($price).';');
```

... but... it looks like you're using Laravel, so you should really be relying on the PDO object to protect you from SQL injection. Using `::raw()` bypasses this protection. In this case, you should be using the `updateOrCreate()` method:

```
TicketRow::updateOrCreate(['ticket_id' => $ticketId], [
        ['row' => $row],
        ['stock' => $stock],
        ['price' => $price]
    ]);
```

The first argument specifies what attribute to examine when classifying the record as new or an update. The second argument passes the values to work with.